# How can i create a map using ros?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone!!
I have a hokuyo laser scanner, kinnect, imu, and other stuff,
How can i create a map using ros?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120626/how-can-i-create-a-map-using-ros?/) by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-01-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi if you want to have map only with laser I suggest you to use [hector_slam](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?distro=hydro&name=hector_mapping). if you want to use hector_slam you need a launch file that you can find it in this [link](http://answers.ros.org/question/64644/how-mapping-using-hokuyo-lidar-urg-04lx-and-hector_slam/) but if you want to use a sensor more than the laser scanner you can use [gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) that uses odometry.

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-01-22**:
Thank a lot.. :-)

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-01-26**:
I do the instruction in the Link and  finally i can create a map but when i run slam.launch( modify of tutorial.launch) below error caused, what's a problem?
[ERROR] [1390736724.097883974]: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to scanmatcher_frame failed: Frame id /map does not exist! Frames (3): Frame /laser exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /base_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

go through this package http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-01-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2